# How to addUniqueObject to non-current user class using cloud code in Parse.com?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to add an array of current user object ID in to a user's column called "followers". Due to Parse's security reason not allowing modification to non-current user, I'm forced to use cloud code. The problem is I know nothing about JavaScript, so I need help here.
Here's what I would code if no security issue mentioned above:

```
//add the current user ID to the user(userPassed) that the current user liked
[userPassed addUniqueObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"followers"];
[userPassed saveInBackground];
```

To be very specific, I just want to know how to code the above in cloud code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('functionName', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;
    var me = Parse.User.current();
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.id = userId;
    user.addUnique('followers', me);
    return user.save(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function(user) {
        response.success('Succeed');
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        response.error('Failed');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi eth3lbert, I changed 'New' to 'new' and it works now. Thank you!